# How to rename the cropped images in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am browsing images from the device, then cropping it using image_cropper in a flutter. Image is successfully uploading to the server. But the problem is when I browse it its directory is so long like as - `/data/user/0/com.example.mera_interest_flutter/cache/image_cropper_1626149199833.jpg`
and this directory name is creating an issue for me. I want to rename it to

`1626149199833.jpg` only, before uploading to the server.

I am using image_cropper:

```
_cropImage(File picked) async {
File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
    statusBarColor: Colors.red,
    toolbarColor: Colors.red,
    toolbarTitle: "Crop Image",
    toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  sourcePath: picked.path,
  aspectRatioPresets: [
    CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
  ],
  maxWidth: 100,
  maxHeight: 100,
);
if (cropped != null) {
  setState(() {
    _pickedImage = cropped;
    print("profilePath" + _pickedImage.toString());
    uploadFile(_pickedImage);
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use `cropped.rename('newname.jpg')` for this purpose.

See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/File/rename.html

Comment: Thank for your reply, it is renaming only last index but i want to rename full path like below :
old path - '/Users/root1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1956F6A0-A6AE-4A45-B37F-F8FF29744971/data/Containers/Data/Application/FECFFAB8-94B0-4049-9822-0EA85244D2C2/tmp/image_cropper_1D2FB77D-0E3A-460C-AB26-89D973B5F1D3-1553-000005D834E7DC00.jpg'

after rename - /Users/root1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1956F6A0-A6AE-4A45-B37F-F8FF29744971/data/Containers/Data/Application/FECFFAB8-94B0-4049-9822-0EA85244D2C2/tmp/photo.jpg'

only last index name is renamed,

Comment: If you use an absolute path you should also be able to rename more than the file itself.

`cropped.rename('/new/path/to/file.jpg')`

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider to find the right path.

Comment: Thank Buddy i do some changes it renames.